# VBA Hyperlinks between Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am working in a large workbook with multiple worksheets and I am trying to write a user form that will display all the worksheets that are in the workbook. I already have the code for identifying all the worksheets in the given workbook and this is already in a text field in a user form. The output is something like that:

.................
Sheet 1  Page1 
Sheet 2  Page2 
Sheet 3  Page3 
Sheet 4  Page4 
Sheet 5  Page5 
Sheet 6  Page6 
Sheet 7  Page7 
Sheet 8  Page8 \

......................

I want to insert a hyperlink in the string "Page number" so that when I click on the corresponding field, the corresponding worksheet is activated. I basically have no idea how to add a hyperlink to a string value without using a cell as a reference.

Here is the code I used to extract the corresponding sheet names and their index:

```
 Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     Dim txt As Variant

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
     
     For i = 1 To WS_Count
        vl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).name
        If txt = "" Then
            txt = "Sheet " & i & "  " & vl
        Else
            txt = txt & vbCrLf & "Sheet " & i & "  " & vl
        End If
     Next i
     Debug.Print (txt)
  End Sub
```

Thx a lot for any help

Comment: Are you attempting to activate the worksheet from the `UserForm`? If so you will want to use the [`Worksheet.Activate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.activate(method)) method.

Comment: As an alternative since you're using a userform, make each of the sheet name a label on a command button. No hyperlinks required.

Comment: FYI Excel already has this feature: [two-tips-for-faster-worksheet-navigation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/10/18/two-tips-for-faster-worksheet-navigation/), [tab-navigation-excel-worksheets/](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/tab-navigation-excel-worksheets/) -- basically you right click on the arrows at the bottom, to the left of the worksheet tabs and you get a list of worksheets that allows you to click any sheet and go to it.

Comment: I know this method, but this is not what I am looking for. For example, the activation of worksheet 9 should be in the string ouput Page 9 from above. So if you click on it, then activate worksheet 9.

Comment: @ topsail, thx I know that too. But I was interesting if I could insert something like a hyperlink in a string value  and display that in a textbox

Comment: I don't know if userforms will work with hyperlinks. Probably not (there is no "insert hyperlink" command that I know of for userforms). You may be able to add buttons, style them to look like hyperlinks, and handle their click events. Userforms are a little primitive though so prepare to be frustrated.

Comment: I just use the userform to display the output in a textbox. I think the question is if vba provides a way to insert a hyperlink in a string value without cell reference

Comment: VBA does not provide a way to insert a hyperlink in a string value, no. All hyperlinks you create with VBA are just automating Excel features provided by the application model. I suppose it's a bit of semantics because we think of VBA/Excel as one thing - but VBA by itself does not have any hyperlink features. I have never seen or used hyperlinks in userforms - I don't think userforms support them but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off using a list box instead of a textbox.  Add a list box to the form as follows:

[image]

Use the default name of "Listbox1". Then add the following code to the userform:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ListBox1.Value).Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    
     For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        ListBox1.AddItem "Sheet " & i & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
     Next
End Sub
```

When you open the form, the listbox will contain a list of all the worksheets.  Click on one to activate it.  If you want to leave the userform open while you work on the worksheets, then open the form with the following line of VBA:

```
userform1.Show false
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Gove. That is essentially what I had in mind. I just had to make one small addition. In the ListBox1_Click() sub, I need to get the "Sheet" & i from the listbox strings because the sheets don't have "Sheet" & i in the original name.

Comment: but that was probably not explained very clearly by me, so I have posted below how I dealt with it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI @Gove

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    
   Dim i, k As Integer
   Dim arr() As Variant
   Dim vl, vl2 As Variant
   
   WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
         
         k = 0
         For i = 1 To WS_Count
            vl = "Sheet " & i & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            ReDim Preserve arr(k)
            arr(k) = vl
            k = k + 1
         Next i

        
   vl2 = ListBox1.Value
   
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If vl2 = arr(i) Then
            j = i + 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Select
            Debug.Print (i & "  " & vl2 & "  " & arr(i))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```